# SQL (Impala) selecting a count of distinct values in one column for each id

Tags: sql, impala

Given a table like the following:

```
+----+-----------+------------------+
| id | diagnosis | diagnosis_age    |
+----+-----------+------------------+
| 1  | 315.32000 | 2.18430371791803 |
| 1  | 315.32000 | 3.18430371791803 |
| 1  | 800.00000 | 2.18430371791803 |
| 2  | 315.32000 | 5.64822705794013 |
| 3  | 800.00000 | 5.68655778752176 |
| 3  | 120.12000 | 5.70572315231258 |
| 4  | 315.32000 | 5.72488851710339 |
| 4  | 315.32000 | 5.74405388189421 |
| 5  | 120.12000 | 5.7604813374292  |
| 6  | 315.32000 | 5.77993740687426 |
+----+-----------+------------------+
```

Each id can occur many times, each id can have many diagnosis, each id can have many diagnosis_age, and each row is unique.

I'm trying to find which id has the most distinct diagnoses.

Something like:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS diagnosis_count 
    FROM diagnoses
        GROUP BY id
    ORDER BY diagnosis_count DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Returns:

```
+------+-----------------+
| id   | diagnosis_count |
+------+-----------------+
| 8    | 8557            |
| 99   | 7828            |
| 127  | 7592            |
| 39   | 6812            |
| 2173 | 6492            |
+------+-----------------+
```

But this doesn't really solve my problem. This works if you define each row as being a diagnosis (which I suppose you could, since each row is unique). If instead, you wanted to get a count of the distinct diagnosis codes for each id (id 1 would have 2 distinct diagnosis codes despite having 3 rows), or alternatively, get a count of the distinct diagnosis_ages for each id (id 4 would have 2 distinct diagnosis_age), how would you go about doing that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(distinct diagnosis) AS diagnosis_count 
FROM diagnoses
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY diagnosis_count DESC;
```

Comment: Oh sweet, thank you so much! Didn't realize distinct could be used liked that within a function.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff Ah no, sorry for that, I thought I had forgotten to accept it previously.